# i have a search function which render another page with search results and i have implemented pagination within this function but it shows me an error

Tags: django, pagination

I have a view function named named search_user and when i type something to search it shows me the results but when ever i click the next page after searching it shows me valueerror(e.g. return none instead)

views.py

```
def search_user(request):
    query = request.GET.get("q")
    context ={}
    if query:
        users = User.objects.filter(Q(username__icontains=query))
        if users:
            page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
            paginator = Paginator(users, 1)
            try:
                users = paginator.page(page)
            except PageNotAnInteger:
                users = paginator.page(1)
            except EmptyPage:
                users = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
            context={'users': users}
            return render(request,'user/search.html',context)
        else:
            messages.warning(request,'User matching query does not exist.')
            return redirect('acc_req_list')
```

form

```
<form class="ml-5" action="{%url 'search_user'%}">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm input-group-solid" style="max-width: 175px">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q"  placeholder="Search users..." value="{{ request.GET.q }}" required />
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

search.html

```
   {% if users.has_other_pages %}
    <ul class="pagination">
      {% if users.has_previous %}
        <li class="page-item active">
            <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ users.previous_page_number }}">pre</a>
        </li>
      {% else %}
        <li class="page-item disabled"><span></span></li>
      {% endif %}
      {% for i in users.paginator.page_range %}
        {% if users.number == i %}
          <li class="page-item"><span style="z-index: 1; position: relative; display: block;padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem; margin-left: -1px; line-height: 1.25; color: #f7efef; background-color: #F64E60; border: 1px solid #E4E6EF;">{{ i }} <span class="sr-only" >(current)</span></span></li>
        {% else %}
          <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% if users.has_next %}
        <li class="page-item active">
            <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ users.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
        </li>
      {% else %}
        <li class="page-item disabled"><span></span></li>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

[image: this is where i am searching a username by driver]

[image: 2nd one is the searching resuls.as i have thre users with this name it is showing me 3 pages which is perfectly right]

[image: but the moment i click any other pages it shows me this big fat error]

Comment: You haven't returned any response in case `if query:` evaluates to `False`...

Comment: Can you please explain what would be the logic if query evaluates to False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return something **if query==False**:

```
def search_user(request):
    query = request.GET.get("q")
    context ={}
    if query:
        users = User.objects.filter(Q(username__icontains=query))
        if users:
            page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
            paginator = Paginator(users, 1)
            try:
                users = paginator.page(page)
            except PageNotAnInteger:
                users = paginator.page(1)
            except EmptyPage:
                users = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
            context={'users': users}
            return render(request,'user/search.html',context)
        else:
            messages.warning(request,'User matching query does not exist.')
            return redirect('acc_req_list')
    else:
        return redirect('URL')
```

### Update:

**search.html**:

Pass **q = {{request.GET.q}}**

```
    {% if users.has_other_pages %}
        <ul class="pagination">
          {% if users.has_previous %}
            <li class="page-item active">               
     ➡➡➡➡<a class="page-link" href="?page={{ users.previous_page_number }}&q={{ request.GET.q }}">pre</a>
            </li>
          {% else %}
            <li class="page-item disabled"><span></span></li>
          {% endif %}
          {% for i in users.paginator.page_range %}
            {% if users.number == i %}
              <li class="page-item"><span style="z-index: 1; position: relative; display: block;padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem; margin-left: -1px; line-height: 1.25; color: #f7efef; background-color: #F64E60; border: 1px solid #E4E6EF;">{{ i }} <span class="sr-only" >(current)</span></span></li>
            {% else %}
     ➡➡➡➡<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}&q={{ request.GET.q }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          {% if users.has_next %}
            <li class="page-item active">
     ➡➡➡➡<a class="page-link" href="?page={{ users.next_page_number }}&q={{ request.GET.q }}">Next</a>
            </li>
          {% else %}
            <li class="page-item disabled"><span></span></li>
          {% endif %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: but then how i will be able to paginate if i redirect to some other url.i need to paginate from that result page

Comment: Hello @ZahidHassan plz see my updated answer.It's works perfectly.

Comment: thank you so much..you are boss. you are superb , i love you,but can you explain how you got this logic.

Comment: Most welcome @ZahidHassan. When you press `next` or `previous` link at that time your past query par. is gone. So I thought about how to keep the past `GET` query par.? Then I applied this my upd. answer in my past projects and it's work...